# How to introduce a Many2one field value in an Odoo database through an XML file?

Tags: xml, odoo, many-to-one, odoo-8

I'm working with Odoo 8 and I'm trying to introduce data in the database through a XML file.

The content of this file is the next one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="event_invitation_email_template" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">Event Invitation</field>
            <field name="subject">Invitation to an event</field>
            <field name="email_from">${(object.event_id.user_id.email or &apos;noreply@localhost&apos;)|safe}</field>
            <field name="email_to">${object.email|safe}</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

This works great. But I want to add another field, `model_id`, which is a `Many2one` (pointing to `ir.model`). I would know how to do this if the value I want to set had XML ID, but it is not the case.

I want to set the model *my.new.model* as the `model_id`, but I don't know its ID in database if I don't do a search.

So I have no idea how to manage my purpose. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Background:**

At loading data by installing resources (models, fields, model-records, views, record rules, actions, menu entries, etc.), Odoo registers mapping records for all resources in the 'ir_model_data' table ('ir.model.data' object), so we can reference those records later, even from other modules.

**Mapping records in 'ir_model_data' have the following remarkable columns:**

- **module:** module name, string literal (not its id)
- **model**: fully-qualified dot-separated object name (also known as the object's technical name)
- **res_id:** The resource id/Database ID (the PK of the record in the table where the resource is stored)
- **name:** record name, a string literal that in conjunction with the module name uniquely identify the record/resource

The record name in conjunction with the module name form what we know as the resource External ID which has the following fully-qualified form: **'module_name.resource_name'**.

Records defined in XML data define their External IDs by means of the 'id' attribute of the 'record' tag.

The 'id' attribute can explicitly include 'module_name.' (fully-qualified form) or not. In the later case (relative form) the module that declares the resource is assumed:

- https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/tools/convert.py#L707

The above long story was required to have enough background for the answer that follows.

**Answer:**

At processing child 'field' tags of any 'record' tag, the 'ref' attribute is expected to have the External ID of a referenced existing record (fully-qualified or relative form):

- https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/tools/convert.py#L727
- https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/tools/convert.py#L836

Mapping records that reference models are created at initializing modules/models/fields. As they lack a corresponding XML record and cannot declare its corresponding External ID by this means, the ORM creates its External ID based in the 'model_' prefix and the object's technical name (dots replaced by underscores):

- https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/models.py#L382

This is why records that reference models ('ir.model' records) have the following form: model_XXXXX

**Records for some other resources also have known prefixes for their External IDs:**

**Modules:** https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/modules/db.py#L90

**Models:** https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/models.py#L382

**Fields:** https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/models.py#L444

```sql
 SELECT * FROM "ir_model_data" WHERE name LIKE 'module_%'; -- most are 'ir.module.module' records
 SELECT * FROM "ir_model_data" WHERE name LIKE 'model_%' ORDER by module, name; -- all/most are 'ir.model' records 
 SELECT * FROM "ir_model_data" WHERE name LIKE 'field_%' ORDER BY module, name; -- all/most are 'ir.model.fields' records
```

Records for other resources may follow some convention or simply not:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "ir_model_data" WHERE name LIKE 'view_%' ORDER by module, name; -- all/most are 'ir.ui.view' records
SELECT * FROM "ir_model_data" WHERE model LIKE 'ir.ui.view' AND name NOT LIKE 'view_%' ORDER by module, name; -- 'ir.ui.view' records with unconventional names
```

So in your case, the line you're looking for is:

```
<field name="model_id" eval="ref('your_module.model_my_new_model')"/>
```

Comment: This is a great answer @Jainik! I'm only going to edit it to add the line of code I've had to write to manage my purpose.

Comment: Ooo... I would be so happy if all the odoo sources I can find on the net would be so HQ.